# Block launching Azure VMS & VMSS from Azure marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-policy

We are planning to block launching of VMs & VMss from azure marketplace and allow only shared image gallery via azure policy , below is the one which i created, please suggest is there any more parameters to consider blocking from market place?

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Block VM or VMSS creation other than Trusted images",
        "description": "This policy enables you to restrict VM & VMSS creation from market place",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Compute"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "publishersToExclude": {
                 "type": "Array",
                 "metadata": {
                      "displayName": "Excluded Publishers",
                      "description": "An array of publishers to exclude from evaluation, such as NVAs"
                 },
                 "defaultValue": [
                      "cisco",
                      "microsoft-aks",                     
                      "microsoft-ads",
                      "AzureDatabricks"
               ]
            }
         },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                       "field": "type",
                       "in": [
                            "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                          "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                       "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                       "notIn": "[parameters('publishersToExclude')]"
                    },
                       {
                       "not" : {
                           "anyOf": [
                         {
                           "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.imageReference.id",
                           "contains": "Microsoft.Compute/galleries"
                         }
                       ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },        
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to block market place images and its working as expected, checking if the policy is correct or anything more parameters needs to consider to block market place completely

Comment: You should post the whole Azure policy definition including the parameters, etc.

Comment: And it is unclear if your policy is working or not - are you just after more things you can check or is it actually not working? According to this it seems like your policy should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-generalized-image-version?tabs=rest%2Ccli2%2Ccli3%2Ccli4#your-own-gallery

Comment: @Niclas i have modified the code and tested the launching VM from market place and its working as expected but as i am new to policies trying to find is there anything missed or if there are any parameters to consider to block market place images completely

Comment: if it is working, I assume you are already blocking marketplace images with this policy? Are you concerned that there might be another way to circumvent the policy and use marketplace images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to block market place images and its working as expected, checking if the policy is correct or anything more parameters needs to consider to block market place completely

Your policy restricts the creation of `VMs` and `VMSSs` from the `Azure Marketplace`, except for trusted images in the shared image gallery.However, there are a few other parameters that you may want to consider adding to your policy to further restrict the creation of `VMs` and `VMSSs`.

You can restrict the creation of `VMs` and `VMSSs` based on the **SKU** and **Offer** of the image used. For example, you may want to allow only certain **SKUs** and **Images** that are approved by your organization.

**Here is the updated policy .**

```json
    {
      "mode": "Indexed",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "in": [
                "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets"
              ]
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
              "notIn": "[parameters('publishersToExclude')]"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.imageReference.id",
                    "contains": "Microsoft.Compute/galleries"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSku",
                    "in": "[parameters('allowedImageSKUs')]"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "in": "[parameters('allowedImageOffers')]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "publishersToExclude": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Excluded Publishers",
            "description": "An array of publishers to exclude from evaluation, such as NVAs."
          },
          "defaultValue": [
            "cisco",
            "microsoft-aks",
            "microsoft-ads",
            "AzureDatabricks"
          ]
        },
        "allowedImageSKUs": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Allowed Image SKUs",
            "description": "An array of allowed image SKUs."
          },
          "defaultValue": [
            "allowed-sku-1",
            "allowed-sku-2",
            "allowed-sku-3"
          ]
        },
        "allowedImageOffers": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Allowed Image Offers",
            "description": "An array of allowed image offers."
          },
          "defaultValue": [
            "allowed-offer-1",
            "allowed-offer-2",
            "allowed-offer-3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

You can select the `Image SKU's` and `Image Offer`  as per your requirement.

[image]

This will restrict the creation of `VMs` and `VMSSs` to only those images that match the specified offer and `SKU`.

[image]

The policy is blocking all `SKUs` except the specified ones.

[image]